# When incrementing double pointer position by 1 the resultant is zero but when incremented by 2 it's the actual value initialised

Tags: pointers

So I need some help understanding the behaviour at which pointer have, so I have code like this below:

```
double d1 = 3.5;
double *d1ptr = &d1;
```

when I increase the pointer position by 1 I get zero i.e `d1ptr = d1ptr+1` but when increased by 2 i.e `d1ptr = d1ptr + 2` I get the first initialised value that is 3.5

However what is weird that I see is that when I increase by any number greater than 2 the pointer value when I print out gives me 0 i.e when I say `printf("%d", *d1ptr)`

Can you please explain the behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print double using `%d`, which will result in undefined behavior. Please use `%f` or `%lf` so that you can get the expected output.

```
double d1 = 3.5;
double *d1ptr = &d1;
printf("%lf %u\n", *d1ptr, d1ptr); //prints value and address
d1ptr = d1ptr+2;
printf("%lf %u", *d1ptr, d1ptr);   //prints value and address
```

Output:

```
3.500000 2255690064
0.000000 2255690080
```

The address has been increased by 2*(size of double)

Comment: After the change you still have undefined behaviour, d1ptr+2 is undefined.

Comment: `d1ptr+2` increments the pointer by 2*(size of double). How is this undefined? @gnasher729